# Make context menu selection more difficult for some items

Tags: c++, qt

Let's say I have a QMenu with two actions "clone" and "delete". To avoid unwanted "delete" I would like to reduce the probability of a click on the "delete" action, instead of putting warning messages that may be very annoying.

The way I would like to implement it is to reduce the action geometry of "delete" when the mouse is outside while restore it to default values when the action is hovered. In this way it should feel like an entering barrier.

Do you have any other alternative ways of doing it?

Like use in some smart way separators?

Comment: Sorry, but that seems like a horrible idea to me. Better to have a confirmation message, perhaps with the option to turn all such confirmations off - than to 'resist' what a user tries to do, which will be very weird and annoying to users who do know what they're wanting to do.

Comment: @underscore_d :D maybe, but the option to turn these confirmations off is also a no for me.

Comment: So just make the button red or orange or italic or something else that indicates warning, but which does not slow down and irritate those who are confident they know what they're clicking.

Comment: @underscore_d Though I fully support your point, I remember with scare all these discussions with beta-testers and users which are unable to not to click a delete or stop button if they don't want to delete or stop. This seems to be the red button labeled "Do not press me!" which ensures that it's always pressed with the respective complaints afterwards that the button does what it's supposed to. This seems to be one of the central but under-estimated issues of GUI design. (Needless to say that my delete and stop buttons are _always_ red...) ;-)

Comment: @underscore_d the color clearly gives a hint, but it does not protect from "slightly moving the mouse while clicking". I mean, if the user really wants to click delete, it will go to its center

Comment: As an alternative why not make it such that certain 'dangerous' actions can only be triggered if the mouse button is used in conjunction with a certain set of keyboard modifiers?  Should be easily achievable with either an event filter or by subclassing `QMenu`.